# How can I make this code for a mathematical problem more efficient

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve problem 5 from project euler with python. However, the code is not fast enough to give an answer within a reasonable amount of time. I'm a relatively new programmer, and very new to python. The problem is

2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder. What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

my code is

```
def divisible(num):
    for i in [20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11]:
        if num % i == 0:
            continue 
        else:
            return False
        return True

num = 2520
while not divisible(num):
    num += 2520
print(num)
```

Comment: Your code is reasonably efficient, to my eye - there are some optimizations possible but nothing that I would expect to significantly change your running time. If I were you I would look for an entirely different approach than counting upwards and checking. I don't want to be _too_ explicit if you're doing this for a learning exercise, but there are some mathematical properties about divisibility that can help you calculate a value from the list of factors rather than by a brute-force search.

Comment: Why not multiply? we know from 1 to 10 so we can continue `2520 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19` Multiplying by prime numbers...

Comment: Thanks! I'll try changing my approach.